# Spark installation in 4 nodes without Hadoop, YARN or Meso?

Tags: apache-spark

I understand spark enables to download and set up in a single node without Hadoop installation. **Is it possible to install spark in multi-node (4 nodes) without resource manager like YARN or MESOS and based on unix file system?**

My understanding is that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Spark Standalone with as many JVM processes or servers, as necessary for workers.

Mesos project had been moved to Apache Attic at one point, and currently has very few core maintainers, if any. I'm not sure there is much activity on Spark for it, given that Kubernetes is more popular nowadays. Many companies still using Mesos (e.g. Twitter) claim to be running a heavily modified fork.

However, you will still need a distributed filesystem for Spark to co-locate files for workers. Otherwise, code running on "server 2" can only access files **on that server**... This is more why you'd use HDFS, but you can use MinIO, Ceph, Ozone, etc as alternatives for Spark as well

HDFS works best with YARN...